# What is the proper way to prove the following question on asymptotic notation?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have to prove that f(n)= 5n+2=O(n^2) and I know that it is true for O(n) so obviously, it will be true for a higher degree of n but how to prove this?

Comment: The first step is to insert the definition of `O` (if this is for class, you should use the version that you've been taught in class) and then continue from there.

Comment: There exists some `M` and `n_0` such that `abs(5n+2) <= M*n^2` for all `n>n_0`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here is a simple way of proving this. I'm including it here in the hope that it could be useful for others with similar problems

```
5n + 2 <= 5n + 2n         ; n >= 1
        = 7n              ; always
       <= n*n             ; n >= 7
        = n^2             ; always
```

Therefore, there exists a constant `c`, in this case `c=1`, and an integer `N`, in this case `N=7`, such that

```
5n + 2 <= c*n^2         for all n >= N
```

Then, by definition

```
5n + 2 = O(n^2).
```

Note also that the first two lines

```
5n + 2 <= 5n + 2n         ; n >= 1
        = 7n              ; always
```

are enough to show that `5n + 2 = O(n)`. In this case, `c=7` and `N=1`.